# Why should mean be constant (and not zero) in stationarity definition?

Tags: time-series

A process is stationary if it has finite variance, constant mean, and time-independent autocovariance. We require stationarity to fit ARMA models.

But as far as I am aware, ARMA-type models do not have a constant intercept term.

So how come we are okay with defining weak stationarity as having constant mean $EX_t = m$? Surely if we fit ARMA to such a sequence, it won't be able to match the intercept. It will be centered around zero, while the actual sequence could be far away from zero.

Is it not more natural to demand that $EX_t = 0$ (which follows easily by subtracting $m$ from $X_t$)? Then the ARIMA model will fit $X_t$ much more naturally.

Comment: Why do you think that "ARMA-type models do not have a constant intercept term"?  See for example formulations on the wikipedia page, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive–moving-average_model.

Answer (score 2):

ARMA models *do* have a constant term (e.g. see the definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive%E2%80%93moving-average_model)). Of course, you can avoid having to think about it by subtracting the mean, as you mentioned.

More broadly, stationarity is a general property of time series, and not all stationary processes are ARMA processes.